# Add Rule to jQuery idealforms

Tags: jquery, idealforms

I am trying to add extra rule to idealforms validation when field current_year is less then 3 and it doesn’t work. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#current_year').on("input", function() {
    var dInput = this.value;
    console.log(dInput);
    $('#current_year').text(dInput);


    $('form.idealforms').idealforms('addRules', {
        'postcode3': ( parseInt( $('#current_year').val() ) < 3) ? 'required' : '',
    });
});

      $('form.idealforms').idealforms({

      silentLoad: false,    

      rules: {
        'postcode2': 'required',
        'memo1': 'required',
        'current_year': 'required',
        'current_month': 'required'
      },


      onSubmit: function(invalid, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#invalid')
          .show()
          .toggleClass('valid', ! invalid)
          .text(invalid ? (invalid +' invalid fields') : 'All good!');
      }
      });
```

Comment: jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/ymfvqyob/3/

Comment: IdealForms -> https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms